# How to do insertion with JPA OneToOne relationship using ORACLE database?

Tags: oracle, jpa, one-to-one

I'm having a problem with JPA OneToOne relationship, and I spent 4 days trynig to resolve it but with no success.
First of all, seeing that oracle does not support Generate.Auto for primary key, we have to create trigger before insertion using a sequence.
And here is my 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE address (
 ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 CITY varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 COUNTRY varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 STREET varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 SUBURB varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE utilisateur (
 ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 EMAIL varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 FIRSTNAME varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 LASTNAME varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PASSWORD varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
 USERNAME varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 ADDRESS_ID INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT FK_USER_ADDRESS_ID FOREIGN KEY (ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES address (ID)
)
```

and the triggers for the instertions:

```
create SEQUENCE address_seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER address_trig
  BEFORE INSERT ON address
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 :new.id := address_seq.nextval;
END

create SEQUENCE user_seq
/




CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER user_trig
  BEFORE INSERT ON utilisateur
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 :new.id := user_seq.nextval;
END;
/
```

the entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UTILISATEUR")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_SEQ", sequenceName = "USER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String username;

    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Address address;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "User_userid")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "Role_roleid")})
    private List<Role> roles;

    public User() {
        roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
        address = new Address();
    }

@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_SEQ", sequenceName = "USER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
.....
```

the creation methode:

```
public void create(T t) {
        this.em.persist(t);
        this.em.merge(t);
    }
```

in order to create a new user this methode is called:

```
 public void doCreateUser() {
        try {
            addressService.create(address);
            newUser.setAddress(address);
            userService.create(newUser);
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("utilisateur ajouté avec succès");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           ....}
```

The insertion is successful using MySQL, but when I configurate the pool to use ORACLE I get an error which means that the foreign key is violated, knowing that while debugging I see the object address created and inserted into the user, but at the end of the methode I get this error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (FK_USER_ADDRESS_ID) violated - parent key not found
Error Code: 2291
Call: INSERT INTO UTILISATEUR (id, EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PASSWORD, USERNAME, ADDRESS_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [7 parameters bound]
```

Thank you for any help about it.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove any triggers from your tables - JPA will do all for you. Read carefully about primary key values generation through sequences.

Comment: Now, after removing triggers, I can insert a new user only one time, the second insert I get this error:     
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS_C007049) violated  
which means that the value of the primary key of the "address" table that is created by the sequence is not unique.

Comment: Please, correct adf to your question code after editing.

Comment: Sorry @Alexender, I am new to Stackoverflow, and I did not understand your meaning in your last comment. Woud you clarify it please ?

Comment: Sorry, I have a mistake in my message. Please correct your question - add your variant of code after editing and show new error message with stacktrace

Comment: I did not edit the code, I have just removed triggers, the fIrst creation is done succefully, but the second one can  not be done throwing the error of "primary key violation".   
when I see the value of the sequence after the insert I notice that the sequence doesn't increment however the ID is incremented. It's weired.

Comment: Can show code of problem entity creation and persisting?

Comment: It's looks safely. Can you prepare simple example which will demonstrate the problem?